# customize from address of email

Tags: email, laravel-4.2

I am using Laravel 4.2. I don't want the default 'from address' which is given in config->mail.php file to be used everywhere in my application. I need to use another 'from address' on another page. How can I do this?

```
$emails = [$formData["inputEmail"]];
Mail::send('emails.testview', array('formData'=>$formData), function($message) use ($emails){
            $message->from('test@example.com', 'test');
            $message->to($emails)->subject('test subject');
         });
```

Comment: Please show the part of your code that is sending email (which you want to set a custom `from` address)

Comment: Please edit your question and add code there. I can see you're setting `from` address, so what is the problem then? What do you expect your code to do that it already does not?

Comment: I have removed the global 'from address' in the config -> mail.php file. But I am getting an error while trying to send email

The error is: 

Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "test@example.com" using 2 possible authenticators